# How to restrict Laravel API to only front-end and mobile client?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have an API written with Laravel as back-end, I also have a front-end application (React) and mobile application (Android) to consume the API.
How can I restrict my API to only the front-end and mobile client and prevent requests from other sources like postman or insomnia ?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve so by leveraging CORS.
It stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. CORS is a security feature to prevent unauthorised access.

https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/laravel-cors/